# Err mysql not found

Tags: java, mysql, database, exception, xampp

```
PreparedStatement codePull = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT tanCode FROM `tancodes` WHERE (tanIndex= "+Tindex+")");
        ResultSet DbTcode = codePull.executeQuery();
        String answer = DbTcode.getString("");
        return answer;
```

this is the code I am using, but the problem is I get an error that says:
ERR:   java.sql.SQLException: Column '' not found.

but I can see that it does exist in the Table!

Any ideas on how to solve it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your query like this:

```
 "SELECT tanCode FROM tancodes WHERE tanIndex= '"+Tindex+"'"
```

And here write the name of column like:

```
 DbTcode.getString("tanCode");// for example
```

Because `"it is:   "` it is not the name of column.